# Concatenate two list based on the same index

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists.

```
A = [1,5,10]
B = [72,36,58]
```

I'd like to concatenate two lists based on the same index.

```
Output = [1,72,5,36,10,58]
```

I know I can use `zip(A,B)` to do so but in this way I need to remove tuple from the list.

Any hint or elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> [i for tup in zip(A,B) for i in tup]
[1, 72, 5, 36, 10, 58]
```

If you are dealing with huge datasets, using `Numpy` extension is a good choice for you, which in that case you would be able to use a lot of cool features. And in this case you can use `numpy.hstack()` to flatten the `zip()` result :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> np.hstack(zip(A,B))
array([ 1, 72,  5, 36, 10, 58])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) approach:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(A, B)))
[1, 72, 5, 36, 10, 58]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something likes this should do the job:

```
A = [1,5,10]
B = [72,36,58]

Out = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    Out.append(A[i])
    Out.append(B[i])
```

And you get:

```
Out = [1, 72, 5, 36, 10, 58]
```